# Custom wordpress query string remover

Tags: wordpress

I got this code in my Wordpress theme function.php file for removing Query Strings from Static Resources. However, I would like to be able to remove query strings with different arguments as well, like **?v, ?rev**. I realize I just could change the **"?ver"** to **"?"**, but then it would also remove google map URL's like **"?pb"** which I don't want. How can I add multiple arguments to this code?

```
// Remove Query Strings from Static Resources
function _remove_script_version( $src ){
  $parts = explode( '?ver', $src );
    return $parts[0];
  }

add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make if conditional if $src contains specific characters or words here is an example

```
function _remove_script_version( $src ){
if (strpos($src, '?pb') !== false || strpos($src, '?apikey') || strpos($src, '?allowedstring')) {
// do nothing for allowed query string
    $parts = $src;
}   
else {
    $newparts = explode( '?' , $src );
    $parts  = $newparts[0];
}
return $parts;
}
add_filter( 'script_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
add_filter( 'style_loader_src', '_remove_script_version', 15, 1 );
```